# how to set unique key on two columns in mysql & oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table patients,unique key is pat_number.

But I want to make unique key on **pat_number** & **branch_id** which already exist in table,in that case i tried this

```
ALTER TABLE patients
ADD CONSTRAINT pat_number UNIQUE (pat_number,branch_id);
```

But branch_id can be same for patients.

Answer (score 0):

syntax seems to be fine for, reason it may not be working as you may have data which is violating the constraint. (It means non unique combination for - pat_number & branch_id) This is just a guess, as Rick mentioned in comment if you can show us data and error message then that will help  us to understand further.